# App update for removed countries in google play store

Tags: google-play-store, updates

An Android app was available in all countries in the playstore.
After a few months, the app was removed from one country ("country XXX")

what will happen if a new version of the app becomes available on the play store : will Google push this new version and update the apps that were downloaded in "country XXX" ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't. You can control distribution in any way you want without changing the application binary, so doesn't make sense that a new updated version will change distribution control.

From https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#distribution-controls

> You can use controls in the Google Play Developer Console to easily
>   manage the geographic distribution of your apps, without any changes
>   in your application binary. You can specify which countries and
>   territories you want to distribute to, and even which carriers (for
>   some countries). When users visit the store, Google Play makes sure
>   that they are in one of your targeted countries before downloading
>   your app. You can change your country and carrier targeting at any
>   time just by saving changes in the Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: Hi Tiago7! are you SURE that it won't, or do you mean "it should not because that would be weird..."

Comment: I am sure, I have published applications before, I am just trying to explain why that is the way it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "country xxx" won't get added if I don't select it myself. But it is not that clear to me what happen to apps that were already downloaded in this country. Did you experience it or read it in some google documentation?

Comment: just found this : All filtering restrictions are associated with an application's version and can change between versions. For example, if a user has installed your application and you publish an update that makes the app invisible to the user, the user will not see that an update is available  (cf http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)   I understand that you are right

Comment: AFAIK this answer is wrong. An app that has been downloaded at least once is "owned" by you and usually even country restricted apps can be downloaded in the wrong country if you "own" them.